# In 3D: column major, row major, ... major?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, matrices

If we use column and row major to describe dimension-majority for x and y respectively, what word is commonly used (if any) to describe such majority for the z dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no such term.

The terms relate a linear representation of a two dimensional matrix in memory to a two dimensional representation "on paper". For higher dimensions this does not really make any sense since there is no such natural representation which you can relate it to.

Also, only specifying majority would not suffice for higher dimensional arrays, you would need to specify at least N-1 dimensions, leaving the last one to be inferred, to specify the linearisation of your multidimensional matrix.

Comment: Your last statement rings true and I had this in mind while writing the question but didn't really know how to broach it. In one sense, it renders the question invalid; in another, it indicates that the wording would need to be e.g. "layer-row-major order" for 3 dimensions... What are your thoughts on this? Am I completely off the mark or does it sound logical?

Comment: I would just steer clear of it, more than likely the actual in memory serialisation is not really important. You will probably not share the memory with code out of your control that needs to know the serialization, nor will you need to be concerned with memory access efficiency unless you are working on very large data sets. Remember that the whole concept is only of use when discussing an actual implementation, as long as it is theory the whole point is moot and when you have an implementation, just note the axis order in the definition.